# Make certain part of string bold using preg_replace()

Tags: php

I have a string of a comment that looks like this:

```
**@First Last** rest of comment info.
```

What I need to do is replace the ** with `<b>` and `</b>` so that the name is bold.

I currently have this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\*\*/i', '<b>$0</b>', $comment);
```

But that results in:

```
"<b>**</b>@First Last<b>**</b> rest of comment info"
```

Which is obviously not what I need. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better idea would be to use a markdown parser library which does this for you.
Improper use of the regular expressions can lead to security vulnerabilities with unclosed tags etc..
However, a simple approach could be this:

```php
$result = preg_replace('/\*\*(.+)\*\*/sU', '<b>$1</b>', $comment);
```

The U means ungreedy and takes the first possible match.
The s modifies `.` to be any character, including newline.
(see [modifiers page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php))

This also works with an example text like this:

```
**@First Last** rest of comment info **also bold**.
The next line also **has a bold example**. This spans **two
lines**.
```

I am sure there are counter examples which are broken with this. Again, please use a proper markdown library to do this for you (or copy their implementation if the LICENSE allows it).